# eclipse bug? services cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse

I have several java projects in an eclipse helios workspace. I want to reference the classes from project A in project B. In project B, I go to properties-->project references and check the box for  project A. But when I try to import the classes from A using an import statement, I get errors "cannot be resolved to a type." Am I missing a step? Is there something wrong with Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your Project A to the buildpath of Project B.
Properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects -> Add...

I actually don't know what the Project References thing does, looks like it's just some kind of mental help for non-Java projects.

Comment: thanks that did it. I am coming from the .NET world where you just need a project reference.

Comment: I am guessing it adds an external source to project B. As far as I can tell, this is more or less eclipse's implementation of a reference variable. Just a pointer to the original Source folder.